# How to parse url to get desired value

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing

How can I parse a link in jqueryjavascript?

I have the url (some path)/restaurantProfile.php?id=51

And I want to parse this to only obtain the 51. (keep in mind this needs to be generalized. The id won't obviously be always 51...)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string at `id=`:

```
var url = 'some/path/restaurantProfile.php?id=51';
var id = url.split('id=')[1]; // 51
```

Answer (score 1):

I forget where I saw this, but here is a nice jquery function you can use for this:

```
//jQuery extension below allows for easy query-param lookup
(function($) {
    $.QueryString = (function(a) {
        if (a == "") return {};
        var b = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
        {
            var p=a[i].split('=', 2);
            if (p.length != 2) continue;
            b[p[0]] = decodeURIComponent(p[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
        }
        return b;
    })(window.location.search.substr(1).split('&'))
})(jQuery);
```

Usage like so:

```
var restaurantId =  $.QueryString["id"];
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can make use of Regular Expression in javascript. `RegExp` Object provides    methods to Match the Regular Expression with a input String.
2. You can make use of `string` object `split` method to split the string by using a separator character.

There is a similar question at [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript?answertab=active#tab-top) for more options.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the URLSearchParams API to work with the query string of a URL

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

```
// get the current url from the browser
var x = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

// get the id query param
var id = x.get('id');
```